# Minimal complexity for pairing two comparable sets with comparability restrictions

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, sorting

A project at university (whose deadline has passed by now) presented the following problem:

> Consider two finite sequences of (not necessarily distinct) real
>   numbers $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ and $b_1,\ldots,b_n$ such that the $b_k$'s
>   are a permutation of the $a_k$'s. The aim is to create an algorithm
>   which returns a permutation which maps the sequence $(a_k)$ onto
>   $(b_k)$. In order to find such permutation it is necessary to compare
>   some numbers during the algorithm. The restriction is that one cannot
>   compare any $a_x$ with an $a_y$ or a $b_x$ with a $b_y$: all that is
>   allowed is to compare a number of the first sequence with one of the
>   second sequence.

I am wondering what would be the minimal (worst-case) complexity of the number of comparisons. It's not hard to get $O(n^2)$: for every $a_x$, search brute-force for a corresponding $b_y$, which costs $O(n)$ comparisons giving a total of $O(n^2)$.
A bit smarter would be to adapt the familiar [QuickSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) algorithm, in the recursions step taking as a pivot a couple $(a_x,b_y=a_x)$ (which can be found in $O(n)$ comparisons) and partitioning both sequences using this 'pivot'. This gives $\Theta(n\log n)$ comparisons in average, but still $\Theta(n^2)$ worst-case (as usual with QuickSort).

It's not hard to see that $\Omega(n\log n)$ is a minimum: represent a given algorithm as a binary decision tree with a comparison at each node. Since the total number of leaves can reach $\Theta(n!)$ (the number of permutations in case all the $a_k$ are different) the height of the tree is at least $\Omega(\log_2(n!))=\Omega(n\log n)$.

It seems likely that a $O(n\log n)$ algorithm exist, but I have not been able to find one. I have tried adapting [MergeSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort), but a problem during the merging arises giving a worst-case of $\Theta(n^2)$ nonetheless.

Is this a known problem? Does a $O(n\log n)$ algorithm exist? Do you have suggestions for other known sorting algorithms which might be adapted without increasing their complexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the famous "[nuts and bolts](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~naor/PUZZLES/nuts.html)" problem.  Yes, there is a randomized algorithm with expected running time $O(n \lg n)$, using a QuickSort-like algorithm.

The problem is famous because there is a simple *randomized* algorithm that achieves $O(n \lg n)$ expected running time.  However, it's very challenging to find a *deterministic* algorithm with a $O(n \lg n)$ time running bound.  Therefore, it makes a nice illustration of the utility of randomness.

The problem is described in several algorithms textbooks, including CLRS and Skienna's textbook.

Comment: Thanks. However the randomized algorithm is still $\Theta(n^2)$ in worst-case. Do you know of any deterministic algorithm with worst-case complexity $O(n\log n)$?

Comment: @barto, I encourage you to click through the link I gave you.  It already answers your question -- it has a citation to such a deterministic algorithm.  (P.S. For practical purposes, worst-case running time is usually not the right way to measure the performance of a randomized algorithm.  I believe the probability that the randomized algorithm takes longer than $c n \lg n$ is exponentially small in $c$.)

Comment: Right, I didn't read that last sentence. The article by Komlós, Ma and Szemerédi can be read on [Google Books](https://books.google.be/books?id=iGv_2NQulz0C) (pg. 232)